# Deletion of my answer did not lead to reputation loss

Tags: bug, reputation, deletion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently (more than 24 hours have passed) one of my [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586069/p-1xxn-n-in-mathbbn-has-only-simple-roots/2586073#2586073) got deleted, as collateral damage.

However, it is strange that my points +98 (10-2) have not been revoked. In my experience when I was deleting my answers (which have been plenty mind you), by myself, the rating points associated to my answers were nullified. However, this is the first time one of my answers have been deleted because the question was deleted.

This must be a bug, right? I hope I am not jumping the gun here.

Comment: Duplicates [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24905/reputation-tab-seems-to-be-insensitive-to-deletion-of-upvoted-answers), seems [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/do-you-lose-the-reputation-points-you-acquired-from-a-question-if-when-it-is-d/150096#150096) applies in your case.

Comment: Oops, I thought I cannot vote to close as duplicate as there is no answer for the other question... @martin

Comment: @JohnMa Oh cool, I didn't know about this feature. I am not sure how I feel about this, as the losing of reputation would be a good deterrent answering questions that have been deemed worthy of deletion. I can see the point of the feature, however.

Comment: A related recent question: [Does reputation change if an answer gets deleted due to deletion of original post by vote(s)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31176)