# Does reputation change if an answer gets deleted due to deletion of original post by vote(s)?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I recently found that the following post [$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k＝1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!\sqrt{k}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117742/lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtxe-x-left-sum-k%ef%bc%9d1-infty-fracxk) was deleted by vote(s) and as a result my answer also got deleted.

> Does such deletion affect my reputation score?

Also I had later on asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143250/evaluating-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1) linking the above post. This deletion actually results in loss of context for my post.

It is the correct response if low quality questions are closed (and that should be enough) but should such posts be allowed to be deleted especially when there is an answer to the question that might help others in future?

Comment: Why was the question deleted, was a PSQ?

Comment: @Bellatrix Yes.

Comment: If it's PSQ then they have all the rights to vote to delete.. but it's not big deal because you can vote/suggest to undelete and then to ask OP to add context, if OP doesn't, then you could add context. It's 100% permitted.

Comment: @Zacky I see .. then that's a problem. Users don't get notified if a certain post gets deleted and neither does it show where the rep was lost.

Comment: If you think a post should be undeleted, then you can post it[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/515527) or in this [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle) and it might get easier attention in order to be undeleted. Also note that there exists an edit button and you can improve that question yourself. I believe that if there's an good answer then even if the question is posed bad it shouldn't be deleted since overall it makes an useful post.

Comment: Related post on [meta.se]: [Do you lose the reputation (points) you acquired from a question if/when it is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13762#150096) Related posts on this meta: [Reputation tab seems to be insensitive to deletion of upvoted answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24905) and [Deletion of my answer did not lead to reputation loss](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28272).

Comment: The linked question is really nice and your answer to it is also great. Once it gets reopened do try to improve it.

Comment: @r9m I have edited the question so that it mentions a post on MO which links to it. Maybe you could also edit it to explain how your question is related to it. Perhaps the fact that this question and its answers are referenced in other places might be an argument in favor of keeping it. (Or if it gets into a deleted/undelete cycle, maybe historical lock could be considered.)

Comment: `Users don't get notified if a certain post gets deleted and neither does it show where the rep was lost`-- this is true.  However, that positive rep does disappear from your rep history; and so you can see which rep has disappeared, and then you know that a question has been deleted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, yes, points gained on answers that get deleted because the question gets deleted are lost. Following an  undeletion the points are restored.

**However,** if your post satisfies both of:

- has score at least three
- was visible<sup>1</sup> on the site for at least 60 days prior to deletion

then you get to keep the points.

See [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/) by Josh Heyer, aka Shog9.

Thus, in the specific case you keep the points.

---

(1) Here "visible" means "not deleted." In particular, the absolute age of the post is not the only criterion, which is relevant in case of multiple deletions and undeletions.