# Why did I lose 40 rep overnight?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

Yesterday I had reputation 7098, and now I it is 7058. What happened? Is it connected to the ongoing personal baiting campaign on me?

Comment: When you're looking [at your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) what do you see? Have you checked the option "show removed posts"?

Comment: @MartinSleziak indeed, I have -40 reps for one post that has been removed, and I even cannot see it as the link does not work.

Comment: @Annix Could you be a bit more specific and explain what you mean by "the link does not work"?

Comment: @MartinSleziak I cannot read the question now, as I can usually read the deleted questions of mine. Its caption in the reputation tab became black, without URL link.

Comment: You could try whether Google remembers that question or whether you have the question in your browser history. You can also have a look at various posts here on meta for suggestions how to look for deleted posts: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: @MartinSleziak no problem with that, I have an improved version of that question posted on Mathoverflow and it currently has positive vote count. But I wonder why some questions get (automatically?) erased without trace and with reputation loss.

Comment: Reputation is not the point. The point is the overall score. The question was received... ambivalently. And that was enough to have it removed.

Comment: @Anixx If the link to the help center (given in the accepted answer) is not sufficient to you can have a look at various sources which are linked in the tag-info [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info) and [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info).

Comment: Since you've mentioned that you have posted (some version of) this question on MO, didn't you include link to the post on [math.se] on that question? It is recommended practice when cross-posting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that is strange, in another thred I read about automatic question deletions, but as I understood it, the questions should be closed, have no reopen votes and basically as a result get deleted rather than erased (with reputation remaining in place and the question retaining ability to be improved by the author).

Comment: That seems to describe a whole other set of circumstances.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so, what's so gross about this question, that it got entirely erased, without ability to improve, copy text, etc?

Comment: You keep saying that, but it's accessible to you through "recently deleted posts", it is accessible to users with 10k or more that have the link, you can copy the text, etc. Stop throwing around these claims. You seem to know very little about the underlying software.

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh I see. Indeed, it is accessible via another page.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak honestly, I am afraid the crowd on this site who downvotes and closes my questions will follow there. That's why I usually do not provide crosslinks in the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an additional question how to find the deleted post in question. As I have mentioned in the comments, you can check some advice given here: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

In this specific case, I looked at list of your questions using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1234402/all-questions-by-a-specific-user?userid=2513). This shows the status when the data in SEDE were last updated - so it includes the questions which were deleted since then. I saw that two among your recent questions are now deleted: [What's the sum of this series? $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(2^k-1\right) B_{k-1}}{2^k}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177605) and [We know that $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$, is there another similar example in other extensions of reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4170423). (The first one should cause *positive* reputation change when it was deleted - since it had 3 downvotes and no upvotes.) Here is a [similar query for answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1234440/all-answers-by-a-specific-user?userid=2513).

As Asaf Karagila mentioned in the comments, since these posts are not older than 60 days, you should be able to find them also using "deleted recent questions".

---

I will add that in some cases the OP keeps the reputation also if the post is deleted. See: [Does reputation change if an answer gets deleted due to deletion of original post by vote(s)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31176) and some of the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/31176).

You have also asked about roomba. Asaf Karagila's answer already contains a [link to the help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). If you want more information, you can check the stuff linked in the tag-info [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info) and [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info).

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative, I did not know about the possibility of database queries.

Answer (score 10):

One of your questions was removed by the [roomba service](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). It had +5/-5 votes to it, which sum up to +40 points.

Since the question is removed, the reputation is lost. No humans intervened in the deletion, so nobody is out to get you.

Comment: Thanks. What is roomba and why it removes posts in such a way that even I cannot access them?

Comment: Roomba service elicits a very adorable image. Love it.